# How do I migrate from PropertyFileSnitch to GossipingPropertyFileSnitch in DataStax Enterprise?

Tags: cassandra, datastax-enterprise

I have followed [this link](https://docs.datastax.com/en/dse/6.0/dse-admin/datastax_enterprise/config/configCstarRackDCProps.html#configCstarRackDCProps__conf-gpfs) to migrate `PropertyFileSnitch` to `GossipingPropertyFileSnitch`  but I'm getting this error:

```
INFO  [DSE main thread] 2022-09-08 14:12:44,295  StorageService.java:286 - Detected current DSE version 6.8.23 in local info
ERROR [DSE main thread] 2022-09-08 14:12:44,297  CassandraDaemon.java:938 - Cannot start node if snitch's data center (dc1) differs from previous data center (DC1). Please fix the snitch configuration, decommission and rebootstrap this node or use the flag -Dcassandra.ignore_dc=true.
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3):

That almost sounds like the case between the data center names is different...  "DC1" != "dc1".

Double check the data center names in the `cassandra-rackdc.properties` and `cassandra-topology.properties` files.  If it was `DC1` in the topology file, you'll want to make sure that it's also set similarly in the rackdc file:

```
dc=DC1
```

Answer (score 3):

It seems like you're following the correct procedure in [Switching snitches in DSE](https://docs.datastax.com/en/dse/6.8/dse-admin/datastax_enterprise/operations/opsSwitchSnitch.html).

The only thing is that you haven't configured the GPFS properties file correctly.

When using the `PropertyFileSnitch`, the default DC and rack configuration in `cassandra-topology.properties` looks like this:

```
10.1.2.3=DC1:RAC1
```

so you would have configured your nodes to be in `DC1`.

But it doesn't seem like you've configured the properties for `GossipingPropertyFileSnitch` correctly. The default configuration for `cassandra-rackdc.properties` is:

```
dc=dc1
rack=rack1
```

You need to override the default and make it the same as your nodes' existing configuration, for example:

```
dc=DC1
rack=RAC1
```

This should allow you to start DSE successfully. Cheers!